# Is it possible to use flat bar shifter on a smart trainer that has Tiagra 4700

Tags: compatibility, turbo-trainer, tiagra

Specs:

- Tacx Smart Trainer
- Shimano 10sp cassette
- Shimano 10sp chain
- Tiagra Rear derailleur

Just wondering, given the difference in price between STI and flat bar shifters, can I just use a flat bar Tiagra 10sp shifter? I don't need a brake or front derailleur, just 10 cogs and Rouvy. I can adjust realness if hills are too hard.

Answer (score 1):

No restriction on the type of shifter.

To my experience with indoor trainer: either you need only one cog (ERG mode), or the same range as in real life. Unless you plan to do rides with constant slopes (flat or not).

Comment: Sorry I re read my post and its hard to understand the question. Its more... can I use a flat bar shifter with the tiagra deraileur i have (4700)...... I think both sti and flat bar (have I got the nomenclature right even?? use the same 4700 deraileur...just that is a 50% cost saving thats all, why have a set of realistic 2x 10 when I can just use the 10x cassette and one front ring...i can allways switch the chain on the front ring by hand before the ride if is hilly

Comment: Tiagra is one of the ranges where both STI and flat bar shifters are offered, so you can choose which one to use (but use only Tiagra 4700 flat bar shifters with a Tiagra rear derailleur - MTB 10 speed shifter are not compatible). Hilly means it goes "up" and "down" in the same ride. If you have budget constraints, my recommendation is just to avoid the shifting at all and use the trainer in ERG mode. But otherwise, better to use a front derailleur, as in real life: pedaling at high cadence is very unpleasant on a trainer (and front derailleur are not expensive).